# Is it ok to share a comment field with multiple content types?

Tags: nodes, comments, 10

Imagine I want to convert individual forum threads (topic + comments) into a content type 'Blog post' to preserve them for the long term.

In order to make this work, the comment field of 'Blog post' needs to be identical to that of 'Forum topic' (this is a limitation of the conversion module currently in beta). Thus I simply re-used the comment type `comment_forum` also for 'Blog post', which works fine.

Now I wonder if that'll cause problems in the long term. At least it seems pretty counter intuitive to use `comment_forum` for anything other than 'Forum topic'. I do not yet fully understand what the implications are of sharing a comment field with multiple content types.

Should I go ahead? Are there better ways to accomplish this?

Comment: If the comment field has to be literally identical, then this is the only solution. Even if you just mean it has to have the same field and storage settings it probably doesn't change anything - sharing fields across multiple bundles is common, encouraged even, that's why the API goes out of its way to allow it. Aside from the potentially confusing field name, I'd say you don't have anything to worry about